# Bash script get user and change dir

Tags: bash, dir

How can I combine these two examples with pushd and whoami to change the directory?

I know I can change the directory like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
pushd /home/mike/Pictures > /dev/null
# do something in the new dir
ls
popd > /dev/null
```

And I know I can get the username like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
theuser=`whoami`
echo $theuser
```

Comment: Uh... change it to what?

Comment: You don't really need `whoami`, if I understand your request correctly. Just `pushd -n ~/Pictures` would do.

Answer (score 3):

You're *waaay* overthinking it...

```
cd ~/Pictures
```

**EDIT:**

Actually, no. What you *really* want is:

```
cd "$(xdg-user-dir PICTURES)"
```

Comment: Ignacio, Do you know if xdg-user-dir comes in Ubuntu natty by default? I mean in a new install, after applying security updates but before applying any recommend updates? Chrisaycock, I read the man for pushd but I still don't understand the -n option. What if I wanted to create a new directory after changing directories? I would need to omit the -n correct?

Comment: @mike: I'm not *certain*, but just in case you could put the result into a variable and use parameter substitution to replace `~/Pictures` if it's empty.

Answer (score 2):

Those backticks can be used to interpolate the output of the command they contain into another:

```
pushd /home/`whoami`/Pictures
```

Comment: Use `$(...)` in preference to back-quotes.  It is especially valuable if you need to nest the construct (which is not the case here).

Comment: Thanks rkb, I took a break then came back and used your option. I still need the `>/dev/null` and `popd > /dev/null` correct?

Comment: Redirecting stdout to /dev/null will hide the normal output of those commands... so if that's what you want, then you still need them =) And popd to get back to the directory you were in before. Lots of good answers here, depending on what you really need to do with your script.

Comment: perfect comment, the backticks are really useful in general - thank you for that info, didn't knew that before.

Answer (score 0):

Much easier than using `pushd` and `popd`, run the command in a sub-shell:

```
(
cd /home/$(whoami)/Pictures &&
ls
)
```

The sub-shell changes directory, without affecting the main process - exactly as you wanted, but rather more reliably.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier just to use `cd` to change the directory:

```
#!/bin/bash    
cd ~/Pictures
```

Answer (score 0):

Among other solutions:

```
pushd "$HOME/Pictures"
```

After all, nothing obliges the home directory to bear the user name!

Answer (score -1):

Bash already has the $USER variable, no need to call an external binary

```
pushd /home/$USER/Pictures > /dev/null
```

Comment: If I go with this do I still need the `popd > /dev/null` ? I guess I don't fully understand what it does.

Comment: If you're running this as a regular script (i.e. it's executable, starts with "#!", and you run it with the filename NOT the `source` or `.` commands), it'll run in a subshell.  This means that when it does a `cd`, the *subshell* cd's to that directory, but *your* shell remains right where it was; when the subshell exits, it doesn't matter where it had cd'd to.  Note that @Jonathan Leffler's answer can be used to force a subshell, in case this is not running as a regular script, or needs to do something back in the original directory after the `ls`.